# Is liberalism with upvotes encouraged?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

After reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276928/312482), a discussion about a particular user's tendency to downvote, I am left with a few questions:

1. are users on SE encouraged to upvote, remain neutral or downvote? (I understand it's the user's decision to cast a vote, but I'm looking for general advice)
2. if it is encouraged, should liberal upvoting be exercised?
3. if it isn't, to what extent is upvoting recommended?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The whole purpose of Stack Exchange is to become a repository of useful questions and their solutions.

Voting is there to get the better answers more visible than the crappy ones. Same with downvoting - keep the good stuff visible, while hiding the bad.

Are people encouraged to vote just for the sake of voting? No. The sites are about quality, not about giving out points. Voting is just a necessary step in order to ensure quality is surfaced. People don't come here to say "*I want to know which question has the most votes*". They come here because "*I have problem {x} and Stack Exchange will have the answer*". And the votes guide them to the solution as quickly and efficiently as they can.

So no, don't vote just for the sake of it. Vote when it's necessary - when content is good, or when content is bad. Think from the perspective of a user 5 years from now. Will your voting on a question / answer now help them when they come here in 5 years?

Answer (score 11):

Users on Stack Exchange sites are encouraged to upvote and downvote often, and as appropriate to the quality of the questions and answers posted.

Sympathy upvoting and vindictive downvoting are discouraged, as is not voting.